# Command not found.when executing bash on remote host

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh, remote-host

Why I cannot execute command on remote host.
Do I miss something?

Bash file:  hello.sh

```
#!/bin/sh 
host_name="myHost"
ssh $host_name  '
STR="Hello World!"
echo $STR
'

executing above file: the print out:
 > ./print_node_status.sh
Enter Windows password: 
STR=Hello World!: Command not found.
STR: Undefined variable.
```

Comment: Not sure why that prompt asks for a "Windows password". I will be assuming that it is a linux node anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your remote shell is [the C shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_shell), not Bash.

You have several options:

- Adapt your code to conform to that shell's language:

```
   ssh $host_name  '
   set STR="Hello World\!"
   echo $STR
   '
```

- Execute `/bin/bash` in your remote process, if it is available, e.g.:

```
   ssh $host_name  '
   exec /bin/bash
   STR="Hello World!"
   echo $STR
   '
```

- Change the default shell of your user on that node to `/bin/bash`, see the [`chsh(1)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chsh.1.html) manpage.